# HTML form POST not getting transfered into php $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Here is my form declaration

```
  <form enctype="text/plain" method="post" action="PI_Application_Submission.php">
```

Here is my input:

```
  <tr><td>Requested User Name<font color="red">*</font></td> <td><input type="text" name="user_name" size="35"></td></tr>
```

Here is my php line...

```
  echo $_POST['user_name'];
```

I know how to check with the isset function and this is not just a warning. For some reason the value of user_name just does not get passed. What am I doing wrong?

My error message is as follows:

```
  Notice: Undefined index: use in /var/www/html/PI_Application_Submission.php on line 6
```

Comment: `Undefined index` either youre specifying the path incorrectly or the page doesnt exist

Comment: Undefined index means that the array has no key with that name; not that the path or page doesn't exist

Comment: Check the error, it tells you, that you trying to read index "use"

Comment: Double check your file names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to removing `enctype` form attribute. 
Basically PHP does not parse POST when your enctype different from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

You can access to raw post data with `file_get_contents('php://input')`

Comment: You sir are a genius. I appreciate all the fast responses guys. I would give you a vote up but I'm too new. :P

Answer (score 0):

You also need an ID attribute on the input element, also, don't forget to close your html tags

```
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" size="35" />
```